# Stopping multiple logins on YII?

Tags: yii

Is there a way to allow only one person to be logged in on an account at any given time? I.e. If I am logged in on PC A, and try to log in on PC B, it must say: "Sorry, you are already logged in." ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table  with the columns session_id and user_id
when ever someone logs in your add that to the table and delete any other rows with that user_id.
whenever a logged in user loads a page you check that table to see if there is a record matching the session_id and user_id
if not you show the error message.